# Semaphore timeout after exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, try-catch, semaphore

I have some trouble managing a resource from multiple modules that can be accessed only once at time securely.

So I tried a named `Semaphore` like this:

```
var semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1, "_UGLY_SEMAPHORE_NAME_");

        try
        {
            var signaled = semaphore.WaitOne(120000); // 2 minutes

            if (!signaled)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Access the resource...
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
```

In the other module I use

```
var signaled = semaphore.WaitOne(0);
```

because the resource shall only be accessed if it has nothing else to do.
It returns steadly after 6 seconds, so the 2 minutes should be enough I believe.

So the question is:

If an exception occurs in the first block of code, afterwards the Semaphore.WaitOne() 
always runs into the timeout. There is something I am doing wrong with it.

Comment: Where is the exception occurring?  Is it in "// Access the resource...", or are you talking about weird edge cases with like thread abort exceptions in unusual places?

Comment: Yes. And it is handled outside of that code and the finally is called. I am a bit confused of the "release increments and WaitOne decrements" part.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `Semaphore` then, or look it up on Google; it's a reasonably well defined CS concept.

Comment: You are right, there is lot of documentation. But if I could find the answer there, I really would not ask that question.

Comment: If you want mutual exclusion, then you should be using a `Mutex` rather than a `Semaphore`.

Comment: Yes, I already thought about that. If I do not get a solution to work, I will try Mutex. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

An exception happening during the processing does *not* result in any other threads waiting on the semaphore waiting around for the timeout.  The `finally` block's semantics mean that it will execute if an exception causes the `try` block to end, which releases the semaphore.

Comment: So, why does it run into the timeout the second time I get into the first block of code after the exception? I am quite sure it is about what I am doing with WaitOne and Release, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: @MareInfinitus Then either you have not shown the actual code you're using, or you're not properly observing the result.

Comment: The code in the question is the code I am using and that I am observing that behaviour. So you think it should work as shown above?

Comment: It does work as shown.  If that is the code that you have, then what you think is happening is not in fact happening.  For example, you may not be waiting on the semaphore that you think you are, or you may not be leaving the `try` block even though the code throws an exception.

Comment: I have breakpoints on the isSignaled and in the finally block. The question is about what I observed. I try to do a smaller example to reproduce the behaviour that I see.

Comment: Yes, I really have a hard time reproducing that issue with a smallish example. Have to observe better or sleep more ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is that you are calling `sempahore.Release()` regardless of whether the thread entered the semaphore.  You should only call `Release` if the code path enters the semaphore, otherwise the counter could get thrown off since your releasing a semaphore when one wasn't acquired.

```
var semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1, "_UGLY_SEMAPHORE_NAME_");

var signaled = semaphore.WaitOne(120000); // 2 minutes

if (!signaled)
{
    return;
}
try
{
    // Access the resource...
}
finally
{
    semaphore.Release();
}
```